# How to get url content through proxy ip and port in php?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I want to get content of some url through the proxy. I had taken proxy ip and port from http://letushide.com/filter/http,all,all/list_of_free_HTTP_proxy_servers

but I am using following code and it return blank page.

```
$url = "http://google.co.in";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) 
        AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
        Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";

$referer = "http://www.google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '190.122.XXX.XXX:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Why you set `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` option?

Comment: No, how to use CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL

Comment: So why you set that option?

Comment: i get this code from other site.

Comment: The fact that you don't need to set `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` option in your case. However the source of problem may be not here

Comment: Ya i removed it but still same problem